# GcmBroadcastReceiver not fired on Android Lollipop

Tags: java, android

I am writing an GCM support for Android 5.0.1. The app registers fine and sending a message to the server also seems ok, however the onReceive method on my BroadcastReceiver doesn't get fired.

But I am able to see my gsm message id in the log cat.

Here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.freshmanapp.gcmtest">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.freshmanapp.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.freshmanapp.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="6" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.freshmanapp.gcmtest.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.freshmanapp.gcmtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.freshmanapp.gcmtest.GcmIntentService" />
</manifest>
```

and here is my GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("GCM Reciever","Triggered");
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.freshmanapp.gcmtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * Created by Ramkumar on 16/04/15.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private static final String TAG = "GCMRelated";

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    String regid;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        startService(new Intent(this, GcmIntentService.class));

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            regid = getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());

            Log.i("Registered Id ",regid);
            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                new RegisterApp(getApplicationContext(), gcm, getAppVersion(getApplicationContext())).execute();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device Registered Now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device already Registered ("+regid+")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
     }


    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(getApplicationContext());
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have got success message in server side, when push notification is sent?

Comment: where is your service class ? also post the whole manifest please

Comment: @harsha, Yes the notification is successfully sent from my server php code.

Comment: do u mean, the callback of GCM server code said, message sent successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `registerReceiver` in your Activity?

You will need to call something like `registerReceiver(new GcmBroadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but it is throwing " Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()" exception